# Need help write a loop in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have data like below in the table. component part no shows the part no replaced for Part no.

[Table having data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESZqt.png)

I want to write a code where I get the last part i.e. the latest part. The loop ends when Part doesnt return anything.

I want to show the data like below:

[How data is needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uioy8.png)

I tried using recursive CTE but the data is huge in table thatit keeps on running for 2 hours.
I am weak in writing stored procedure.
Any way we can achieve it? We are okay if it completes in 1 hour.

Comment: Would you please clarify the exact requirement? If I understand the problem, you need to add a column that captures the PREVIOUS_PART_NUMBER. Is that correct? If so, I'm not clear on the order for what determines the "previous" part. In the first table nothing shows ordering, but in the second table there is a column called PART_LEVEL that looks like a good candidate to determine the previous part. If that's the case, is the PART_LEVEL column on the first table? If not, how do you determine order for what's the previous part number?

Comment: if you have multiple chains, with different levels of nesting/leveling, a recursive CTE is about your only choice. What you ideally want is some extra details so you can partition the data, so chain 1 can be known not part of chain 2 etc etc. Also your recursive data will make 'chains' like `9U8806,1252127,1073295` which is what you want, but also `1252127,1073295` unless you pre-process to find the roots via an left outer join, and then mark those node as roots, and only start the recursion on those nodes

Comment: Also paste pictures of simple data, painful to view, and access for people to help, thus pasting that data in text format also, is nice.

Answer (score 2):

If we need to analyze the level of nesting, CTE is a good solution. The key is to choose the starting point right. Only the roots. So that there will be no infinite loops or duplicate results.

If the CTE takes too long and there is too much data, maybe try to scale up the warehouse or divide the data into batches.

The CTE should look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T1 (
    PART_NO STRING,
    COMPOMENT_NO STRING);

INSERT INTO T1 (PART_NO, COMPOMENT_NO)
VALUES ('9U8806',  '1252127'), 
       ('1252127', '1073295'),
       ('1073295', '1386464'),
       ('1386464', '2320160'),
       ('2320160', '3153441');
           
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT T1.PART_NO AS ORIGINAL_PART_NO, T1.PART_NO, T1.PART_NO AS PREVIOUS_PART_NO, 1 AS PART_LEVEL
      FROM T1
     WHERE T1.PART_NO NOT IN (SELECT COMPOMENT_NO FROM T1) -- only roots
     UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE.ORIGINAL_PART_NO, T1.COMPOMENT_NO AS PART_NO, CTE.PART_NO AS PREVIOUS_PART_NO, CTE.PART_LEVEL + 1 AS PART_LEVEL
      FROM T1
      JOIN CTE ON CTE.PART_NO = T1.PART_NO
)
SELECT * 
  FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Thanks. as I mentioned earlier i tried with CTE but the data is bit skewed hence in any way it goes into infinite loop. I have written a stored proc for the same but the issue now i am facing is insert statements. Going row by row inserts is throwing the performance at back. Need to find a way to send data in batches for insert within stored procedure.